# Windows store app - addEventListener on class

Tags: javascript, windows-store-apps

I realize that is not possible to add `addEventListener` on `document.getElementByClassName` selector. But I have several buttons with identical functionality. Can I do this somehow? Ok I can use id selector, but that way I'll have to add more code lines then "needed".

With jQuery:

```
$(".class").on("click", someFunction);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just iterate through the array returned by document.getElementsByClassName()?

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('foo');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
   elements[i].addEventListner('someEvent', eventHandler(evt), false);
```

It might not be as succinct as the jQuery equivalent but it gets the job done. Alternatively, you could use jQuery in your app(Personally, I haven't tried this out).